# How do I extract text elements between \t and \

Tags: r, regex, string, text, stringr

I am working with some really messy data in txt format, and have an issue where I want specific data filled into a variable but I struggle to extract it. A simple example to illustrate the problem. I want to extract a METACODE: xxxx, where xxxx is any random number depending on the metacode, say 1234 in this case. When inspecting this txt file I see that the character string contains among other things the following when looking at the file I loaded:

```
"\"\t\tMETACODE:\t\t\t1234\""
```

Now I want to extract 1234 or xxxx in general since I have several txt files. I tried using stringr based on another stackoverflow example, but it didn't have the \t and . I tried

```
library(stringr)
metacode <- str_match(textfile, "METACODE:\t\t\t\\s*(.*?)\\")
```

where textfile is the variable containing the text I read in with readlines. I got the following error:

```
Error in stri_match_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)
```

Any good idea for handling \t, \n, , etc? A simple example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the number rather than search for a backslash:

```r
library(stringr)
textfile <- "\"\t\tMETACODE:\t\t\t1234\""
metacode <- str_match(textfile, "METACODE:\t\t\t\\s*(\\d+)")
metacode[,2]
```

**Results**: `[1] "1234"`

See [**proof**](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOrJLWiJC0zJ1XBRldBKUYppiSmxNc1xNHZ38XVCsSJKTE0MjaJUVLiyk0tSUzOTwGrBGqPz00sSc7QgOnXUVBC0xcTU6ylEROToq2ppAnXHK1jFPv/PwA).

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  METACODE:                'METACODE:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \t                       '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \t                       '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \t                       '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason you explicitly included the three tabs instead of just letting `"\\s*"` take care of it? Also, it may be safer to make the whitespace match lazy opposed to greedy (hard to know without a larger sample of the data).

Comment: @Andrew I understand the numbers OP needs to extract must have 3 tabs before. Sure, if there is no strict requirement for tabs, `\\s*` would be enough.